# R: shinyMobile - f7DatePicker not Working on iPad

Tags: r, shiny

Apologies if I am missing any basic information. But, I am using shinyMobile to develop a mobile data collection interface on an iPad. I am experiencing that f7DatePicker is not responding on the iPad. I checked the same code on an iPhone8 with 13.3.1 (software version) and it is working. However, f7Stepper and f7checkBox widgets are working on the iPad. The specifications on the iPad are referred to below,

Device: iPad-Pro(12.9)
Model: ML0N2B/A
Software Version: iPadOS 13.5

Is this an expected issue? Hoping for any feedback to resolve issue.

Thanks